# Form data validation with javascript is not validating input fields

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, form-submit

I've been trying to solve this issue with javascript form validations. I'm submitting with a validateForm() function on the form.

I was expecting the form data to be validated when clicking on submit but it just bypasses every validation and submits the form.

this below is my validation function in the script.js file

```
function validateForm() {
  document
    .getElementById("registrationForm")
    .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
      const dobInput = document.getElementById("dob").value;
      const state = document.getElementById("state").value;
      const postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
      const firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
      const lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
      const otherSkillsCheckbox = document.getElementById("otherSkills");
      const otherSkillsText = document.getElementById("otherSkillsText").value;
      const errorMessages = document.getElementById("errorMessages");
      errorMessages.textContent = ""; // Clear previous error messages

      // Date of Birth Validation
      const dobRegex = /^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/;
      if (!dobRegex.test(dobInput)) {
        errorMessages.textContent += "Invalid date format (dd/mm/yyyy).\n";
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
      } else {
        const [, day, month, year] = dobRegex.exec(dobInput);
        const dobDate = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const age = currentDate.getFullYear() - dobDate.getFullYear();
        if (age < 15 || age > 80) {
          errorMessages.textContent += "Age must be between 15 and 80.\n";
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }

      // State and Postcode Validation

      const stateToPostcode = {
        VIC: ["3", "8"],
        NSW: ["1", "2"],
        QLD: ["4", "9"],
        NT: ["0"],
        WA: ["6"],
        SA: ["5"],
        TAS: ["7"],
        ACT: ["0"],
      };
      if (!stateToPostcode[state] || !stateToPostcode[state].test(postcode)) {
        errorMessages.textContent +=
          "Postcode does not match selected state.\n";
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      // Other Skills Text Area Validation
      if (otherSkillsCheckbox.checked && otherSkillsText.trim() === "") {
        errorMessages.textContent += "Please provide other skills.\n";
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      return true;
    });
}
```

and this is the form in html

```
 <div class="form-container">
                <h1 id="title">Application Form</h1>
                <form id="registrationForm" onsubmit=" validateForm();">
                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <label class="form-label" for="JobRef">Job reference number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="JobRef" id="JobRef" required readonly>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <label class="form-label" for="First name">First name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" id="firstName" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <label class="form-label" for="Last name">Last name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" id="lastName" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <label class="form-label" for="dob">Date of birth</label>
                        <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required>
                    </div>

                    <!-- <span id="dobError" style="color: red;"></span> -->

                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Gender:</legend>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required>
                                Male
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
                                Female
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">
                                Other
                            </label>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <label class="form-label" for="Street Address">Street Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" maxlength="40" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <label class="form-label" for="Suburb/town">Suburb/town</label>
                        <input type="text" name="town" maxlength="40" id="town" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <label class="form-label" for="state">State</label>
                        <select id="state" name="state" required>
                            <option value="">Select a State</option>
                            <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
                            <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
                            <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
                            <option value="NT">NT</option>
                            <option value="WA">WA</option>
                            <option value="SA">SA</option>
                            <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
                            <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                    <!-- <span id="stateError" style="color: red;"></span> -->
                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <label class="form-label" for="postcode">Postcode</label>
                        <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" pattern="[0-9]{4}" required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <span id="postcodeError" style="color: red;"></span> -->

                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <label class="form-label" for="Email address">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <label class="form-label" for="Phone number">Phone number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" pattern="[0-9\s]{8,12}" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Choose your skills</legend>
                            <input type="radio" name="skills" id="Html" value="HTML" required>
                            <label for="Html">HTML</label><br>
                            <input type="radio" id="css" name="skills" value="CSS">
                            <label for="css">CSS</label><br>
                            <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="skills" value="JavaScript">
                            <label for="javascript">JavaScript</label>
                        </fieldset>
                        <br>

                        <div class="mb-10">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="skillsOther">Other Skills</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="skillsOtherCheckbox" id="skillsOtherCheckbox">
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="skillsOther" id="skillsOther" required> </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <span id="skillsOtherError" style="color: red;"></span> -->

                    </div>

                    <div id="errorMessages" style="color: red;"></div>

                    <div class="mb-10">
                        <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: You're adding the `addEventListener` inside the `validateForm` form so you basically just add the event listener on form submission.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the event listeer on form submission. You have to just call the function instead. Remove the `addEventListener`:

```
function validateForm() {
    const dobInput = document.getElementById('dob').value;
    const state = document.getElementById('state').value;
    const postcode = document.getElementById('postcode').value;
    const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    const lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
    const otherSkillsCheckbox = document.getElementById('otherSkills');
    const otherSkillsText = document.getElementById('otherSkillsText').value;
    const errorMessages = document.getElementById('errorMessages');
    errorMessages.textContent = ''; // Clear previous error messages

    // Date of Birth Validation
    const dobRegex = /^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/;
    if (!dobRegex.test(dobInput)) {
        errorMessages.textContent += 'Invalid date format (dd/mm/yyyy).\n';
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
    } else {
        const [, day, month, year] = dobRegex.exec(dobInput);
        const dobDate = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const age = currentDate.getFullYear() - dobDate.getFullYear();
        if (age < 15 || age > 80) {
            errorMessages.textContent += 'Age must be between 15 and 80.\n';
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    // State and Postcode Validation

    const stateToPostcode = {
        VIC: ['3', '8'],
        NSW: ['1', '2'],
        QLD: ['4', '9'],
        NT: ['0'],
        WA: ['6'],
        SA: ['5'],
        TAS: ['7'],
        ACT: ['0'],
    };
    if (!stateToPostcode[state] || !stateToPostcode[state].test(postcode)) {
        errorMessages.textContent += 'Postcode does not match selected state.\n';
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    // Other Skills Text Area Validation
    if (otherSkillsCheckbox.checked && otherSkillsText.trim() === '') {
        errorMessages.textContent += 'Please provide other skills.\n';
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the build in form field validation on all form fields? For a better overview I cut out all the form fields that are OK (they have a pattern /constraint and a required attribute).

Here I have event listeners for invalid, change, input, keyup and submit. The form will only submit if all the form fields are valid. The event listener for submit is just to show when the form submits -- remove that. The event listener for invalid will be called when you try to submit the form or if the function `checkValidity()` is called on the form. It suppresses the default error message by calling `e.preventDefault()` and by setting the `useCapture` parameter to true. Here the classname `invalid` is set on the form field. Interaction with the form is either change, input or keyup. In each case the validity is tested and the `invalid` classname is removed. When the state is changed the pattern of the postcode is also changed, so that they align (I don't know what to test for, so I just use the first number as the first number). Likewise, if the `skillsOtherCheckbox` changes the required attribute for the textarea will be added/removed.

The date is defined initially when the page loads. Here I define the `max` attribute of the `dob` input so that the input is not valid if you enter a date after 15 years ago. A similar value can be defined for the `min` attribute.

```js
const stateToPostcode = {
  VIC: ["3", "8"],
  NSW: ["1", "2"],
  QLD: ["4", "9"],
  NT: ["0"],
  WA: ["6"],
  SA: ["5"],
  TAS: ["7"],
  ACT: ["0"],
};

const currentDate = new Date();
let date15 = `${currentDate.getFullYear()-15}-${(currentDate.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2,'0')}-${currentDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2,'0')}`;
// set the max date to the current date minus 15 years
document.forms.registrationForm.dob.max = date15;

document.forms.registrationForm.addEventListener('change', e => {
  // if the current input is valid, remove the invalid classname
  if(e.target.validity.valid){
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
  switch(e.target.name){
    // when the state changes, update the pattern for postcode
    case 'state':
      let startnum = stateToPostcode[e.target.value][0];
      e.target.form.postcode.pattern = `${startnum}[0-9]{3}`;
      break;
    // when skillsOtherCheckbox is checked the skillsOther should have a value
    case 'skillsOtherCheckbox':
      e.target.form.skillsOther.required = e.target.checked;
      break;
  }
});

document.forms.registrationForm.addEventListener('input', e => {
  // if the current input is valid, remove the invalid classname
  if(e.target.validity.valid){
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});

document.forms.registrationForm.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  // if the current input is valid, remove the invalid classname
  if(e.target.validity.valid){
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});

document.forms.registrationForm.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

document.forms.registrationForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('the form is submitting...');
});
```

```css
span.error {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  font-size: smaller;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.invalid ~ span.error {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <h1 id="title">Application Form</h1>
  <form name="registrationForm">
    <div class="mb-10">
      <label class="form-label" for="dob">Date of birth</label>
      <input type="date" name="dob" title="Age must be between 15 and 80" required>
      <span class="error">Age must be between 15 and 80</span>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-10">
      <label class="form-label" for="state">State</label>
      <select id="state" name="state" required>
        <option value="">Select a State</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
        <option value="WA">WA</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
      </select>
      <span class="error">Select a state</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-10">
      <label class="form-label" for="postcode">Postcode</label>
      <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" pattern="[0-9]{4}" title="Postcode does not match selected state" required>
      <span class="error">Postcode does not match selected state</span>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-10">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="skillsOther">Other Skills</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="skillsOtherCheckbox" id="skillsOtherCheckbox">
      <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="skillsOther" title="Please provide other skills"></textarea>
      <span class="error">Please provide other skills</span>
    </div>
    <div id="errorMessages" style="color: red;"></div>

    <div class="mb-10">
      <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```